# Haskell: Remove html character entities in a string

Tags: html, parsing, haskell, html-parsing

I'm looking to take a string containing html character entities such as `&nbsp;` etc and replace them with the literal string characters. I'm getting data via twitter's api and the text contains those entities. Anyone know of an existing library which does this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would you consider changing the accepted answer (which is a deprecated library and will miss many entities)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Web.Encodings package on hackage looks promising (the decodeHtml function):

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/web-encodings/0.3.0.2/doc/html/Web-Encodings.html

Comment: Be aware that it does not support all HTML entities, only a subset - and it "swallows" any it does not know, ie. they will disappear.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you very much! Might I ask how you found this? I swear I did a fairly thorough search (google, hoogle, hackage) and wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: I searched google for "haskell entity decode" and it was the second entry.  Just a question of knowing you wanted an "entity decoder" and being aware of Haskell's package library, which you already were of course. :-)

Comment: I'd like to revive this question in search of a more general answer, for escaping named HTML entities.

Comment: @vicvicvic: Fair enough, "more general"?

Comment: More general in the sense that it handles all HTML entities, not just the subset supported by Web.Encodings.

Comment: @vicvicvic: Would that not be a matter of simply adding a lot of data to the [Web.Encodings source](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/web-encodings/0.3.0.2/doc/html/src/Web-Encodings.html) - see the `encodeHtmlChar :: Char -> String` functions.

Comment: A revision of this answer would be very helpfull, it seems that the Web.Encodings package is deprecated!

Comment: @HaskellElephant: I see [a message](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2013-April/011759.html) on the [`haskell-beginners` mailing list](http://www.haskell.org/mailman/listinfo/beginners) asking what it is deprecated in favour of.  It mentions the routine [`Text.XML.decodeHtmlEntities`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xml-conduit/1.0.3.1/doc/html/Text-XML-Stream-Parse.html#t:DecodeEntities), which is part of the `xml-conduit` package.  Though said it did not work, it is supposed to deal with the basic entity decodes though.

Comment: Note, that this package seems to be abandoned.  Latest Hackage update was at _Wed Jan 18 17:26:24 UTC 2012_, furthermore related _git repository is missing_ on GitHub.  Due to this I've down voted this answer. One alternative I've found is `html-entities` (but sadly it is not included in LTS Haskell yet) which is MIT licensed ([Hackage page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/html-entities)).

Answer (score 3):

I built the following function with functions from the package `tagsoup`. It handles all named and numeric entities from the HTML5 Standard (more than 2000, [see the list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#named-character-references)).

```
import   qualified          Text.HTML.TagSoup as TS

decodeHTMLentities :: (StringLike str, Show str) => str -> str   
decodeHTMLentities s = TS.fromTagText $ head $ TS.parseTags s
```

`StringLike` has instances for `String`, Lazy and Strict `ByteString` and `Text`.

Unknown entites will be left intact. If you want a warning about unknown entities use:

```
> parseTagsOptions parseOptions{optTagWarning=True} "&asdasd;"
[TagText "&asdasd;",TagWarning "Unknown entity: asdasd"]
```

Answer (score -7):

Hello try the code below it will work out

```
labelTR = labelTR.replace(/(?:&nbsp;|&amp;quot;)/g,'');
```

Comment: I suggest you look up how many possible entities there are: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references
I don't think a regular expression is the way to go. Besides, your solution is not in haskell.

Comment: Although this might work, writing a function for such tasks oneself is not a good idea. A library will alsways contain less bugs, mistakes, etc.